# force fit parent div height to fit lt's child

Tags: css

I want to fit parent div height to fit it's child

that means I want height of parent div to fit  red color

and green part will hide

https://jsfiddle.net/zfpwb54L/

```
<style>
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.section {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.style_content {
    color: #27272a;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9;

}

</style>

<div id="parent" style="background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:fit-content;">
    <div style="position: absolute; inset: 0px;"></div>
    <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
        <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
            <section class="section">
                <div class="style_content container">
                    <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                     <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                     that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                </div>
            </section>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please check it once. This is how you want to have it:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/Lyf6qbtv/11/

Comment: no sir, I want parent to fit child , but you make child fit it's parent

Comment: Which div is parent?

Comment: <div id="parent"

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/zfpwb54L/ I want to fit height  to the red div

Comment: Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/n3q78tfh/2/

Comment: @kairav-thankar , I think this code affect on the parent  , but i do not know how ,   transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);

Comment: This is your solution, Which you asked and for more CSS work please refer to W3school.

Comment: if you make any div container you will show it's not solved ,

Comment: Please share example

Comment: that is your exmple https://jsfiddle.net/s581ycva/

Comment: If you add any more parent div then you need to remove the current parent div inline css and apply it to the new parent div

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/8ocs4g32/

Comment: , as I said to you before , this code transform-origin: right top 0px;transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0); affect on the parent div

Comment: every time you move this code to up , transform-origin: right top 0px;transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0); , you move the issue from child to parent , not solve it,

Comment: Let me know what is your exact concern and what you want because your css will not get you the proper result. So share me the actual thing what you want.

Comment: this exmple for your code , https://jsfiddle.net/u4szxwkd/ , I want all code not affect any div container , you will added

Comment: I have updated the answer with the final solution. Please check the answer revised link again. Hope you will find your solution permanently

Comment: @ kairav-thakar , I want to make  a small content  preview on child  div  , as this code transform-origin: right top 0px;transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0); make samll preview on any child content , and I want to not affect on the parent

Comment: @ kairav-thakar , kairav-thakar  very thanks for your time, and your efforts , you very kindly

Comment: I am happy to help always and very glad you find your solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I simply added

> box-sizing: border-box

to style_content class

```
.style_content {
    color: #27272a;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9;

}
```

Comment: not solve the issue , please can make example